# I want to protect my Azure Web API not be called without authorization

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I wrote a ASP.NET Web API.
And now I have published in my Azure App service, but I found anyone can invoke my API via the Postman.

I would like to only allow the Azure/Microsoft user who has been authorized user can call my API?

How can I achieve this aim?

Comment: Check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview

Answer (score 0):

Just put an API management in front of your API and set it to require subscription key.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-subscriptions

Comment: Don't you think that APIM is an overkill in this scenario? OP just wants to protect their API with Azure AD auth.

Comment: hard to say, I don't have the requirements

Comment: I already create the APIM in my App server. But it seems it is not forbid the API call from the Postman. So I need to configure some parameter to make sure the API only available from the Azure AD?

Comment: no, you must setup to require ocp-apim-subscription-key header.

Comment: regardless of using Azure API Management (or if you wish to skip it), did u configure .AddAuthentication \ .AddAuthorization  on your IServiceCollection, and decorated the controllers with Authorize attribute ?

Comment: I did not configured the AddAuthentication  or AddAuthorization
Because as I know, it will require to expose some API in the Application, right?

So if I just want to using the very simple way to implement it, is any better solution?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio  Regarding the "ocp-apim-subscription-key".

Do you have any sample?

Comment: @jell it's the link I've shared. When you require a Subscription callers will need to provide ocp-apim-subscription key header + the value associated to it (auto generated and you'll find it in the portal)